# onmicrosoft.com FQDN for Microsoft Learn Sandbox 365 tenant

Tags: microsoft-office-365, entra-id, office365, microsoft-365

With [Office 365 tenant restrictions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/tenant-restrictions) in place, access to the Microsoft Learn Sandbox's Office 365 tenant (used by courses such as https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/learn/modules/azure-architecture-fundamentals/exercise-create-website) is blocked:

> Message: AADSTS500021: Access to 'Microsoft Learn Sandbox' tenant is denied.

[image]

There doesn't seem to be anything in Microsoft's documentation for this and a Google search for `Access to 'Microsoft Learn Sandbox' tenant is denied.` returns absolutely nothing, hence this post.
[image]

For now, we've granted access by using the directory ID, `604c1504-c6a3-4080-81aa-b33091104187`, from the URL but this isn't ideal as it's not human-readable.

Does anyone know what the tenant's default AAD FQDN (`<something>.onmicrosoft.com`) is?

I guessed `microsoftlearnsandbox.onmicrosoft.com` and it does exist according to https://login.microsoftonline.com/microsoftlearnsandbox.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration but it didn't work here.

**Edit (2022/03/16 15:36):** While using the Microsoft Learn Sandbox, I happened across a UPN named <username>@**triplecrownlabs.onmicrosoft.com** which is in line with what Bobbert said / found.

[image]

Comment: As Stated, contact your IT-Administrator. `Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault.`

Comment: I am the IT administrator. Contacting the Microsoft Learn Sandbox tenant administrators is likely to be very difficult, time-consuming, and unsuccessful so I was hoping that someone would just know. And if they don't and I do manage to find out myself then I'll post the answer here "Q&A style" which is encouraged.

Comment: Doubt anyone will be able to tell you what the domain name is, since it seems this is not publicly available data. beside, I fail to see the need to have the domain name if you can just use a tenant ID, contact Microsoft directly maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

triplecrownlabs.onmicrosoft.com <- took me forever to find

Comment: How do you know that this is correct?

Comment: @Michael Hampton It does seem to be correct as https://login.microsoftonline.com/triplecrownlabs.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration has the exact same Directory ID GUID that we managed to allow access with. I am curious how Bobbert managed to find it, though.